# How to use nth-of-type to select nested children

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to style odd and even headers that are associated with content.  They are inside several DIVs, and I am unable to get nth-child or nth-of-type to work- only the odd styles are displaying.  Here is some concept code:

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
<h2>Welcome to my blog</h2>
<div class="post">
    <h2><a href="myPostLink">This is a post</a></h2>
    <div class="entry">
        <p>here is some content</p>
    </div> <!-- end entry -->
    <div class="meta"><p>Here is meta info</p></div>
</div> <!-- end post -->

<div class="post">
    <h2><a href="myPostLink">This is another post</a></h2>
    <div class="entry">
        <p>here is some more content</p>
    </div> <!-- end entry -->
    <div class="meta"><p>Here is meta info</p></div>
</div> <!-- end post -->
</div> <!-- end content -->
```

CSS:

```
.content h2 a:nth-of-type(odd){color: #444;}
.content h2 a:nth-of-type(even){color: #ccc;}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/272rq/)

My thought process was that since I was starting at **.content** in my CSS, the first **.content h2 a** would be considered odd and the second even, etc.  Apparently not so- they are all considered the first child. Is there a way to select the headers in the way I want with CSS alone?  Am I doing something dumb?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_combinators.asp

Answer (score 23):

Use `nth-child` on the `.post` elements, and then select the `h2` element from there

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/QLsqh/)

```
.post:nth-child(odd) h2 a {
    color: red;
}
.post:nth-child(even) h2 a {
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
.content div.post:nth-of-type(odd) a{color: #444;}
.content div.post:nth-of-type(even) a{color: #ccc;}
```

The a element of odd and even divs with post class.
Not quite sure if that's what you need.
A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/a4j7z/